# How to checkout and build UIAutomator source code in windows

Tags: java, android, ant, junit, android-uiautomator

I am trying to use **UiAutomatorTestRunner.java** in **UiAutomator.jar** . The default **UiAutomator.jar** which comes with android sdk doesn't have **UiAutomatorTestRunner.java** inside it .  So I am planning to download the **UIAutomator** source code and along with  **UiAutomatorTestRunner.java** from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/99937ceb604da144fd88c028d79fd3b2478f059d/uiautomator/library/testrunner-src/com/android/uiautomator/testrunner/UiAutomatorTestRunner.java and make the **UiAutomator.jar** locally in windows and use it for my automation project .

I need help how to download the source code in eclipse  of UIAutomator (along with the link) and build it locally in windows . Advanced thanks for any help on this .

Comment: Check this http://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/uiautomator-in-eclipse/

Comment: Did you ever get instructions on how to checkout and build Uiautomator source

Comment: I am not getting any clue on net to download the Uiautomator full source code with dependent jars (to avoid compile errors)  and to build it locally (in unix/winodws) to create UiAutomator.jar after some source code modification . one is thre http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/com/android/uiautomator/core/UiDevice.java

Answer (score 1):

1.[Establishing a Build Environment](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)

2.[Downloading the Source](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

3.Building the Target:

```
  $ source build/envsetup.sh
  $ lunch aosp_arm-eng
  $ make uiautomator
```